# ListFragment does not display correctly onCreate(), but is ok after onResume()

Tags: android, android-listfragment

MyActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //list is global var
    list = (MyListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(com.myapp.R.id.mainActivity_myListFragment);
    //add all objects to list
    list.getListView().invalidateViews();
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    list.getListView().invalidateViews();
}
```

MyListFragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(new ArrayList());
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, container);
    TextView main = (TextView) view.findViewById(mylibs.common.R.list_main);
    TextView sub = (TextView) view.findViewById(mylibs.common.R.list_sub);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(mylibs.common.R.list_image);

    //set the View content here.
}
```

The problem is, I can not get the first run to display correctly. However, if `onResume()` is called by Android, it all displays perfectly fine. How do I solve this?

The first item in the list displays correctly at all times, only the rest of the list is problematic.

When debugging `getView()` right after `onCreate()`, it clearly shows that the TextView and ImageView are set by the data that I want in the `getView()` method, but it does not display and instead of showing the data that I want, it shows the `toString()` `String` of the `Object` that's in the `Adapter` for one of the TextView and all others are left blank.

Comment: Can you provide the code of `MyListFragment`? And where do you load the Fragment? In XML?

Comment: Yes, `MyListFragment` is loaded by XML.

Comment: So how's the code of `MyListFragment`?

Comment: I have updated the question. Please take a look.

Comment: You set the adapter to display an empty list during `onCreate()`. What do you expect it to display?

Comment: The adding part was taken out. i believe that I have stated it in the comment. `//add all objects to list`

Comment: And please post your complete `MyListFragment`

Comment: You should add the items in the ListFragment, and set the adapter after you added the items.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Android is a wreck and this is a waste of time.

I am still looking for the answer, but a workaround is to create a new Thread, sleep for 1ms, then `runonUIThread()` `invalidateViews()`.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing some things here which are most likely the root of your problem:

**A)** Fragments are not inflated during your Activity's onCreate() function, so you cannot access them there. The best practice here is to access / manipulate fragment views during the Fragment's own onCreateView() lifecycle callback. This is the point right before they are inflated onto the screen, so the perfect spot. The activity and fragments you create should be relatively independent of each-other. Fragments should be re-usable. For example, what would you do if you needed this fragment in X more activities?

**B)** Your `getView()` is suspicious to me. List views are usually defined by the `listview` view group you have in xml, the adapter (instantiated by `onCreateView()`), your model collection of objects which the list view will contain, and a separate xml with views which define each cell in the list. `getView()` is normally a function you override **within** your adapter (using the view holder pattern), where you access and populate the views that make up a cell from your separate xml.

Maybe you have it set up correctly but what you've given us doesn't read like it (the adapter definitely shouldn't be set in the fragment's `onCreate()` anyway).

[Vogella has a nice tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) on list views. Good luck!